# Многотабличный SQL запрос: обработка связанных данных из второй таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть 2 таблицы. Вторая зависит от первой, то есть `table1.id = table2.cat_id`.

При попытке запросить одну запись первой таблицы и все связанные записи второй таблицы, у меня получается путаница в виде:

```
array('id'=>'1', ..., 'servers'=>'server1');
array('id'=>'1', ..., 'servers'=>'server2');
```

Вместо

```
array('id'=>'1', ..., 'servers'=>array([0]=>'server1', [1]=>'server2'));
```

То есть на выходе нужен один массив с информацией из первой таблицы с вложенным массивом, содержащим данные со второй таблицы.

Данную задачу решаю разбором всех массивов и созданием нового массива с необходимым содержанием, что очень неудобно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную задачу.

Сам запрос

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.class, s.name as servers
FROM cat as c
INNER JOIN servers as s
ON s.cat_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = '$id'
```

Comment: как решаете - так и решайте, по-другому никак, т.к. в реляционных базах нельзя иметь массив в качестве поля (а вы это и хотите получить). Как вариант - сделать, например, `group_concat` по `s.name`, а в коде разбивать это поле на массив, но вариант, скажем так, не очень хороший

Comment: Я думаю вам стоит немного перестроить приложение что бы первый массив был корректен для него.

Comment: @ВОРОН пробовал `group_concat()`, но это тоже не то. То есть, я так понимаю, решить данный вопрос в запросе нельзя, да?

Comment: @Naumov как именно?

Comment: в запросе нет, только в цикле; сейчас еще один коммент напишу как можно сделать, хотя идея все та же

Comment: @mix где массив используеться и для чего?

Comment: @Naumov передаю в шаблон и печатаю

Comment: можно несколько улучшить текущий подход: join'ы оставляете на месте, но в select'е сначала выбираете записи из `cat`, а вторым запросом из `servers`. А потом в коде группируете эти два набора. Т.е. формирование нужного вида все равно остается тем же самым, но возможно сможете увеличить скорость выполнения всей операции за счет того, что join идет по меньшему набору полей, а значит пересылать много данных внутри субд не надо будет, что может повлиять на скорость выполнения. Но здесь прирост скорости может съесть выполнение еще одного запроса. Надо профилировать и смотреть

Comment: @ВОРОН хорошо, спасибо огромное за идеи.

Comment: @mix так на уровне шаблона и рендерьте исходный массив печатаете в смысле pint_r? или на принтере? или ещё как то?

Comment: @Naumov нет, в смысле вывожу. Отправляю в шаблон и там разбираю в цикле.

Comment: @mix отлично так в этом же цикле и перебирайте массив

Comment: @Naumov меня не перебор массива волнует, я подумал будет какой-то способ решить данную задачу на уровне бд. P.S. Не лучшая идея пихать столько кода в шаблон рядом с html. Я привожу массив в нужный вид в контроллере и уже оттуда передаю в шаблон в нужном виде.

Comment: @mix, реляционные базы данных проектировались не для этого, т.е. то, что вы хотите, в них не предусмотрено. Но есть нереляционные базы (NoSQL), сам с ними не работал, но вроде как они могут делать именно то, что вы хотите. Вот только есть ли смысл только ради этого переводить все данные с одной базы на другую (да к тому же и вообще с другой архитектурой)

Comment: @BOPOH я тоже с ними не работал и пока что желания особого нет переходить на них и начинать сначала все разбирать, проект горит, не до этого, мягко говоря)

Answer (score 2):

> Данную задачу решаю разбором всех массивов и созданием нового массива
>   с необходимым содержанием, что очень неудобно.

Полностью отказаться от пост-обработки запроса не получится в силу табличной природы СУБД (как хранилищ, так и ответов). Возможно вам покажется более удобным альтернативный подход, вместо `INNER JOIN` использовать `LEFT JOIN`, а название серверов формировать в виде списка через запятую при помощи функции `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.name,
  c.class,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) as servers
FROM
  cat as c
LEFT JOIN
  servers as s
ON
  s.cat_id = c.id
WHERE
  c.id = '$id'
GROUP BY
  c.id
```

Однако, полученный список серверов `servers` будет именно строкой, чтобы преобразовать его в массив, потребуется дополнительная обработка. Например, можно воспользоваться PHP-функцией `explode()`

```
$result['servers'] = explode(',', $result['servers']);
```

Comment: Только не забывайте что у  `GROUP_CONCAT` по-умолчанию максимальная длина 1024 символа.

Comment: Да, есть такое дело, размер 1024 регулируется директивой group_concat_max_len, которую можно кстати менять динамически, т.е. не обязательно редактировать конфигурационный файл my.cnf достаточно задать необходимый размер для сессии SET @@local.group_concat_max_len=10000;